# Exercising multiple updates within DAML choice

Tags: daml

Is it possible in DAML to use a map-like function to iterate over of list of contractids, retrieve them and execute a choice on each? This appears to be limited in DAML by the way everything needs to be wrapped in a single Update when executing a choice.

Here's an example of what I've attempted (noting the issues):

```
exerciseChoice: ContractId ContractB -> Update (ContractId ContractB)
exerciseChoice contractB = do (exercise contractB UpdateB with newText = "test")

template ContractA
  with
    party : Party
    contracts: [ContractId ContractB]
  where
    signatory party

    controller party can
      nonconsuming UpdateA : [Update (ContractId ContractB)]
        with newText : Text
        do  
          --   a <- create ContractB with party = party; text = newText
          --   a2 <- exerciseChoice a
          --   return [a2] #these lines work fine

          return map exerciseChoice contracts
          -- #this doesn't work due to DAML implicitly adding Update before return definition
          -- i.e. DAML expects type 'Update [Update (ContractId ContractB)]' based on this signature
          -- we need a function which converts something like: 
          -- '[Update (ContractId ContractB)] -> Update [ContractId ContractB]'

template ContractB
  with
    party : Party
    text: Text
  where
    signatory party

    controller party can
      UpdateB: ContractId ContractB
        with newText: Text
          do create this with text = newText
```

If this can be solved, can you also explain why when returning multiple tuples in DAML they seem to implicitly cast from `(Update (ContractId A), Update (ContractId B))` to `Update (ContractId A, ContractId B)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` so `map exerciseChoice contracts` will have type `[Update (ContractId ContractB)]`. Turning a list of actions into a single action is conceptually simple. The resulting action is the action of performing each action in the list in sequence. And indeed, there is a function for that: `sequence : (Applicative m) => [m a] -> m [a]`. `Update` is an applicative so you could write `sequence (map exerciseChoice contracts)`. However, this is such a common task that there is a specialised function `mapA : (Applicative m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`.

`mapA exerciseChoice contracts` should do the trick.

Comment: `mapA exerciseChoice contracts`, without the `return`